# Is there an established phrase like "Claim a false dollar to get a rightful cent"?

Tags: phrases

For example person A believes that person B is occupying 1 acre of person A's land.  Person A claims that person B is occupying 10 acres in the hope that a court of law will award a fraction of the initial claim or in the expectation that person B will settle for a fraction of the original claim. Such fraction equalling the 1 acre which A believes he truly deserves.

The behavior of person A may be seen as dishonest. But person A perceives his behavior as merely "playing the system" in order to achieve his proper rights - i.e. the end justifies the means.

(EDIT)
I have editted the above to exclude the variation where person A hopes to be awarded more than his fair share.  Of course in reality it may be unlikely that person A will be awarded exactly his rightful cent.

Comment: Where did the "false dollar" phrase originate? Acquired somewhere? translated? own invention?

Comment: @thomas. My own invention (unless I picked it up unconsciously).

Comment: Your aphorism reminds me of a famous [_Saturday Evening Post_ magazine cover](http://www.saturdayeveningpost.com/2011/04/30/art-entertainment/beyond-the-canvas-art-entertainment/rockwell.html/attachment/9361003) by Leslie Thrasher. Thrasher (working in the style of Norman Rockwell) called it "Tipping the Scales," but it might more accurately have been called "Tipping the Scales to Balance the Scales."

Comment: @Sven Yargs. Nice illustration. Yes the strategies of the lady in the picture and my person A are similar.

Answer (score 1):

"Dicker, dicker, dicker -- don't pay him the sticker."

This was an expression I heard my father use, back in the 1950's.  I don't know if it is a common expression.  Car dealers use inflated "sticker" pricing, to allow themselves room to bargain and still make a good profit.  If you want to get a fair price, you need to start with an offer that you know is low.  This allows you to negotiate a fair price somewhere in the middle.

I understand that this is actually the opposite of what was requested, but I believe it still pertains.  In a way, the inflated pricing of the dealers is a closer analogy to the topic at hand, but unfortunately, I have no expression to capture the practice of inflating sticker prices.

Comment: Yes "inflating the sticker price" is very similar in concept to the behavior of my person A.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this from a financial justice point of view.  Then I thought to me this means taking the law into one's own hands.  I looked up a word for this because one did not immediately come to mind.

This is what I got:

[Synonyms for taking the law into one's own hands](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take+law+in+to+own+hands)

Can you clarify the question more.  I had to clarify my interpretation of the question as it is ambiguous.  It is an interesting question.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with taking the law into your own hands? Also, clarifications to questions should be asked for in comments to the question, not in answers, which are supposed to be authoritative and able to stand on their own as valid answers.

Comment: Sorry I'm only a member for a few days.  Was only trying to help out.  I have an audit background so this would be my experienced interpretation.  Using false money to get money that is rightfully yours would be my view of getting justice of some kind and thats where the law comes in.  I was backing up my answer with personal experience based on the website's instructions.  But I've learned about the comment thanks for that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the asker’s use of _false_ here. The meaning seems to be making an exaggerated claim for something, hoping that a settlement will be possible that leaves you with a bigger share than you are really entitled to; similar to haggling to beat down the price of something: you offer a ridiculously low amount, the sellers counters with a ridiculously high amount, both hoping to end at a price that’s to their advantage. Actual counterfeit money are not involved. Incidentally, do take a look through the [help], that will tell you much about the place.

Comment: Ah ok now I'm with you.  That's a bit clearer.  I had to do a course in this once.  It was called negotiation skills.  Except in this case the favour is always on the negotiators side?  I believe this is known as collective bargaining, a type of negotiation I used when I was involved in trade unions.  [link](http://hms.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/assets/Sites/Ombuds/files/NegotiationConflictStyles.pdf) may be of interest.  HTH sorry about my answer.

Comment: @OSFox.  You are right, my original question was ambiguous in that person A might have two intents:- (1) to achieve a fair outcome or (2) to achieve an unfair profit.  I have simplified the question to exclude (2).

Comment: @OSFox. Regarding "Taking the law into own hands". I had to think hard about that one.  It does not meet my need because my person A relies on the legal machinery to deliver his desired outcome.

Comment: Are you talking about the opposite of Adverse Possession?  If this is the case I can only think of eviction  or ejection of part B, leading to A getting his / her rightful cent?  Just throwing this out there.  I all out of other ideas.

Comment: @OSFox. Funnily enough adverse possession is a possible play in my particular situation but I don't want to go down that road!  In my case person A considers person B to be in wrongful possession.  The key points are "inflated claim" and "intent for a fair outcome".

Answer (score 0):

"shoot for the moon" or, more aptly, "ask for the moon"

Comment: Certainly there is an element of "asking for the moon" in person A's stratgey but I am hoping for a phrase which also includes the concept of "righting a wrong".

Comment: Perhaps we should say "inflating the demand (or the damages) to get a fair settlement".  That's what is often done in lawsuit negotiations.

Comment: Yes I think that "inflating the claim to get a fair settlement" is a good description of my person A's behavior and intent.  However I was hoping that there would be a "juicier" phrase such as the one in the title such that just using a shortened form (e.g. "Claiming false dollar") would be sufficient to convey the full meaning (to someone familiar with the phrase).  Also "inflated claims" tends to suggest that the claimant is seeking more than a fair reparation.